# Following Start and End Date Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have start and end date columns, and there are some where the start date equals the end date of the previous row without a gap.  I'm trying to get it so that it would basically go from the Start Date row who's End Date is null and kinda "zig-zag" up going until the Start Date does not match the End Date.

I've tried CTEs, and ROW_NUMBER() OVER().

```
START_DTE                   END_DTE
2018-01-17                  2018-01-19
2018-01-26                  2018-02-22
2018-02-22                  2018-08-24
2018-08-24                  2018-09-24
2018-09-24                  NULL
```

Expected:

```
START_DTE                   END_DTE
2018-01-26                  2018-09-24
```

**EDIT**

Using a proposed solution with an added CTE to ensure dates don't have times with them.

```
WITH
  CTE_TABLE_NAME AS
(
  SELECT
    ID_NUM,
    CONVERT(DATE,START_DTE) START_DTE,
    CONVERT(DATE,END_DTE) END_DTE
  FROM
    TABLE_NAME
  WHERE ID_NUM = 123
)
select min(start_dte) as start_dte, max(end_dte) as end_dte, grp
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_dte = end_dte then 0 else 1 end) over (order by start_dte) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_dte) over (order by start_dte) as prev_end_dte
            from CTE_TABLE_NAME t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

The following query provides these results:

```
start_dte   end_dte      grp
2014-08-24  2014-12-19   1
2014-08-31  2014-09-02   2
2014-09-02  2014-09-18   3
2014-09-18  2014-11-03   4
2014-11-18  2014-12-09   5  
2014-12-09  2015-01-16   6 
2015-01-30  2015-02-02   7
2015-02-02  2015-05-15   8
2015-05-15  2015-07-08   9 
2015-07-08  2015-07-09   10
2015-07-09  2015-08-25   11
2015-08-31  2015-09-01   12
2015-10-06  2015-10-29   13
2015-11-10  2015-12-11   14
2015-12-11  2015-12-15   15
2015-12-15  2016-01-20   16
2016-01-29  2016-02-01   17
2016-02-01  2016-03-03   18
2016-03-30  2016-08-29   19
2016-08-30  2016-12-06   20
2017-01-27  2017-02-20   21
2017-02-20  2017-08-15   22
2017-08-15  2017-08-29   23
2017-08-29  2018-01-17   24
2018-01-17  2018-01-19   25
2018-01-26  2018-02-22   26
2018-02-22  2018-08-24   27
2018-08-24  2018-09-24   28
2018-09-24  NULL         29
```

I tried using having count (*) > 1 as suggested, but it provided no results

Expected example

```
START_DTE   END_DTE
2017-01-27  2018-01-17
2018-01-26  2018-09-24
```

Comment: What was wrong with your attempt?   Did you get an error?   What was the exact code you tried, and what was wrong with the result?

Comment: There were failed attempts of various solutions using the mentioned methods in the question. It was more a question of general guidance so that a solution can be found, because what I had wasn't doing much. and wouldn't "flatten" the columns with connecting dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify where groups of connected rows start by looking for where adjacent rows *are not connected*.  A cumulative sum of these starts then gives you the groups.

```
select min(start_dte) as start_dte, max(end_dte) as end_dte
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_dte = start_dte then 0 else 1 end) over (order by start_dte) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_dte) over (order by start_dte) as prev_end_dte
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

If you want only multiply connected rows (as implied by your question), then add `having count(*) > 1` to the outer query.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e3992b6d5c4ecc57d183aaeab987dc9a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for the the proposed solution.  I implemented it, and provided results in the edit to my original question.  I tried swapping prev_end_dte = end_dte with prev_end_dte = start_dte and it provided different grp results, but still wouldn't collapse correctly.

Comment: @jhsh . . . I've included a db<>fiddle with some of your sample data and the code appears to work (with the change to the `case` condition).

Comment: Thanks again.  There must have been something I had different, but yes that does work!